# How to obtain Japanese whisky in Canada?

Tags: whiskey, canada

A few months ago I learned of a popular Japanese whisky, Yamazaki 12. Since then I've been searching, and searching for methods to get my hands on a bottle, but have come up empty-handed.

Being in Ontario it would seem that the only legal method of obtaining any type of whisky is via the LCBO, and so I'm at the whims of what they have in stock. I've looked into online suppliers but it would appear that none of them can legally ship into Canada.

So outside of leaving Canada, and bringing a bottle back in, is there a way to get my hands on any given Japanese whisky?

Comment: The Yamazaki 12 is fairly hard to get anywhere due to surging demand and limited stocks of old spirit at Yamazaki, Mostly what you will find these days are the younger, no-age statement bottlings that they have started releasing to cover this shortfall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can obtain different varieties of Japanese Whiskeys in Canada. The real question (or two) is whether or not you can obtain a particular one and whether it is obtainable in Ontario?

Each province regulates what is permitted to be sold in their liquor stores.
The official provincial list of products will vary from province to province. Here in BC, we can obtain the [SUNTORY WHISKY - HIBIKI JAPANESE HARMONY](http://www.bcliquorstores.com/product/358390) at our Government Liquor Stores. For some reason, private liquor stores can obtain more products from the approved list than can the Government Liquor Stores. Why this is so, makes no sense to me at all. It is what it is.

If I were in Ontario, I would ask the Customer's Services at your neighboring liquor and see if they can obtain a Japanese Whiskey or two. If they can order it in, please be aware that you may have to buy a complete box, especially if the product in question is not a popular item. This is the rule in BC, however private stores often will waive that. **Simply go and ask them in person, I do it all the time.**

Another thing you might try is to go to a *Wine Market or Festival* in your area. You may get lucky.

Although not a Wine Market in the strictest sense please check this out from Alberta: [Kensington Wine Market](https://www.kensingtonwinemarket.com/blog/?p=2661).

> We’re Stocking up with a Dozen Whiskies from Nikka Whisky Co. of Japan.
>
> We love Japanese whisky here at KWM, and feel it is every bit as complex as the best Scotch whiskies. The following whiskies from Nikka Whisky Co. will be in stock at the Kensington Wine Market...

For what was offered at the time see [here](https://www.kensingtonwinemarket.com/blog/?p=2661).

Once again, I encourage you to ask at your local Government Liquor Store in your area.